# How do you peer into the definition of a robust command?

Tags: macros

I know that, whenever I want to see how some control sequence, say `\mycontrolsequence`, is defined, I can use

```
\show\mycontrolsequence
```

then compile my code and look up the .log file. However, robust commands seem impervious to `\show`. For instance, if I compile the following code,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mycommand{foo}
\show\mycommand

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myrobustcommand}{bar}
\show\myrobustcommand

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

my log file contains

> ```
> \mycommand=\long macro:
> ->foo.
> l.4 \show\mycommand
>
> \myrobustcommand=macro:
> ->\protect \myrobustcommand  .
> l.7 \show\myrobustcommand
> ```

Note that, whereas the definition of `\mycommand` is exposed (`foo`), nothing transpires of `\myrobustcommand`'s definition.

Of course, in practice, I could always identify in which file a given robust command is defined and look up its definition there. However, finding the file in question may not be obvious. Hence my question:

**Is there an alternative way of peering into the definition of a robust command?**

Comment: `\usepackage{xpatch}\xshowcmd\mycommand`

Comment: @egreg I just looked up the `xpatch` package. That's cheating, egreg: you're the maintainer of that package :p Your comment answers my question completely. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's already something about this on the site. I'll try finding it; failing, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Commands defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` are defined in an indirect way; when you say

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{...}
```

LaTeX defines `\foo` as

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\expandafter\protect\csname foo \endcsname}
```

so that it internally uses a `\foo`  command (with a trailing space in its name) and does

```
\@namedef{foo }{...}
```

This is a rough approximation, actually. So, to find the actual definition you have to say

```
\expandafter\show\csname foo \endcsname
```

The situation is *much* more complicated when you do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1][default]{...}
```

because the command above would not answer anything sensible.

You can load the `xpatch` command (or `regexpatch`) and use

```
\xshowcmd\foo
```

which will do the right thing for you.

If you load `regexpatch` you'll have also a *-variant that shows more information. For example, after

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\foo[1][default]{something with #1}
```

you'll get, from `\xshowcmd\foo` the output

```
> \\foo =\long macro:
[#1]->something with #1.
```

while `\xshowcmd*\foo` will tell

```
*************************************************
* xpatch message
* `\foo' is a control word defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand' and a default
* optional argument `default'
*************************************************
> \\foo =\long macro:
[#1]->something with #1.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. `\xshowcmd*` is especially handy.

Answer (score 7):

[A quick work-around](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds) is to define

```
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}
```

which "intercepts" the `\protect`ion. Note the localized redefinition of `\protect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}

\newcommand\mycommand{foo}
\show\mycommand

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myrobustcommand}{bar}
\pshow\myrobustcommand

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

The `.log` file shows:

```
> \mycommand=\long macro:
->foo.
l.5 \show\mycommand
                   

> \myrobustcommand =\long macro:
->bar.
\myrobustcommand ->\protect \myrobustcommand  
                                              
l.8 \pshow\myrobustcommand
```

Comment: Let me one more question. Suppose I (or some package) made a command through \newcommand. Say, 
\newcommand{\mycmd}[2][1st]{foo}. Is it possible to watch how did LaTeX internaly created it? I tested this by \pshow but no avail. Latex returns something like \@protected@testopt ...

Comment: @maximav: For this you should `\usepackage{xpatch}` and then you can use `\xshowcmd\mycmd`.