# The \show command displays not all command

Tags: debugging

The TeX-primitive \show displays text of a command but I observed that not all, say LaTeX's commands, have been exhibited by this way. Opinions and solutions of experts please.........

Comment: perhaps you have been using it on a so-called `robust` command? for example `\show\newline`? Then `\expandafter\show\csname newline \endcsname` with a crucial space before `\endcsname`. More convenient: use `latexdef\newline` in a command line console.

Comment: Yes, it does; it's only that some of the LaTeX commands have a more complex definition than one may expect. Can you give some examples?

Comment: I'll do this, dont remember right now

Comment: May be related to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117169/how-do-you-peer-into-the-definition-of-a-robust-command