# Why do some font commands behave differently?

Tags: fonts

I've always been confused by the differences in behavior of font commands.

For example, we have `\mathrm{}` and `\texttt{}`, which can be used like this: `\texttt{hello} world`.

And then we have `\it` and `\bf` which must be used as `{\it hello} world`. If one uses `\it{hello} world`, both words are italicized.

Internally, what is the difference here? And was this difference a conscious design decision? If so, why?

Comment: You shouldn't use `\it` and `\bf`, but `\itshape` and `\bfseries`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)

Comment: Maybe worth a look my answer at [`\bfseries` is to `\textbf` as WHAT is to `\textsf`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139592/4918) …

Answer (score 8):

Primitive font commands (none of which you show in your example) work like `\bf` and affect all text for the rest of the current group so the usual syntax is `{\it hello\/}` although the outer group isn't needed, you could do `\it hello\/ \rm world` with no grouping.

The syntax is efficient but somewhat counter-intuitive but in plain TeX and LaTeX2.09 all font commands were that way. LaTeX2e introduced and encouraged the `\textit` form which uses an argument syntax and automatically handles italic correction `\/`. They are actually simple wrappers around the declaration forms such as `\itshape`. The old "2-letter" names like `\bf` that were defined in plain and LaTex2.09 are not defined at all in the latex2e format but many classes include a compatibility package that defines them for old (ie pre 1993) document fragments. `\bf` is then defined to be more or less `\normalfont\bfseries`.

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing *switches* with *macros*. While the former is still a macro (in the TeX sense), it *does not take an argument*. As such (and I'm using the preferred choice as contained within [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764)), using

```
\itshape{hello} world
```

makes `\itshape` span within the group that it's used, and there's none there. However,

```
{\itshape hello} world
```

prevents the *switch* `\itshape` to span outside the group in which it's used. `\texttt` (and friends) take an argument, and then place it inside a group. You can see this by viewing the `.log` file after compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117169/5764
\begin{document}
\pshow\texttt

test
\end{document}
```

The `.log` shows

```
\texttt =\long macro:
#1->\ifmmode \nfss@text {\ttfamily #1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}
\ttfamily \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi .
```

where you can clearly see `\texttt{<stuff>}` translates to the grouped `{\ttfamily <stuff>}` (simplified).

Comment: There *is* a difference between `{\itshape abc}` and `\textit{abc}`, which is the reason why the latter form is to be preferred.