# Why does \show\jobname result in \jobname and not the name of the file?

Tags: macros

Should not the name `\jobname` expand to the name of the file without the extension?

I looked at

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36967/13552

It says that show results in the meaning of a macro. Does my result imply that `\jobname` is not a macro?

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\show\jobname
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Ouput:

```
> \jobname=\jobname.
l.4 \show\jobname
```

Comment: `\showtokens\expandafter{\jobname}`

Comment: or `\message{HERE \jobname}`, `\wlog{HERE \jobname}`, `\typeout{HERE \jobname}`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\jobname` is not a macro (essentially it's not defined with `\def`) it is an expandable primitive that expands to the filename.

You can make a macro with the same expansion

```
\edef\xjobname{\jobname}

*\show\xjobname
> \xjobname=macro:
->texput.
```

so `\xjobname` has the same expansion as `\jobname` but they have different `\show` behaviour and crucially they are not equal if tested with

```
\ifx\jobname\xjobname
```

but two macros with the same expansion are `\ifx` equal.

Answer (score 5):

Typically that's the way TeX primitives react. From [the TeXbook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (**Chapter 3: Controlling TeX**, p 10):

> How can a person distinguish a TeX primitive from a control sequence that
>   has been defined at a higher level? There are two ways: (1) The index to this
>   manual lists all of the control sequences that are discussed, and each primitive is marked with an asterisk. (2) You can display the meaning of a control sequence while running TeX. If you type `\show\cs` where `\cs` is any control sequence, TeX will respond with its current meaning. For example, `\show\input` results in `> \input=\input.`, because `\input` is primitive. On the other hand, `\show\thinspace` yields
>
> ```
> > \thinspace=macro:
> ->\kern .16667em .
> ```
>
> This means that `\thinspace` has been defined as an abbreviation for `\kern .16667em`. By typing `\show\kern` you can verify that `\kern` is primitive. The results of `\show` appear on your terminal and in the log file that you get after running TeX.

Commands that are declared in a [robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764) way have a similarly bizarre output even though they are declared as a "macro". For example, `\show\vspace` prints

> ```
> > \vspace=macro:
> ->\protect \vspace  .
> ```

in the terminal.

[Some primitives can be expanded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288811/5764) and there is also a way around [peeking inside the definition of robust commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117169/5764). For those primitives that cannot be expanded, you'd have to look into [TeX The Program](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TexTheProgram) - [the `.web` code](http://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web) or [its documentation](http://brokestream.com/tex.pdf) - in order to understand what it's doing.

Using [David's example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288811/5764) that input the following in the TeX terminal (no filename specified):

```
\edef\xjobname{\jobname}

*\show\xjobname
> \xjobname=macro:
->texput.
```

> **528.** Initially *job_name* = 0; it becomes nonzero as soon as the true name is known. We have *job_name* = 0 if and only if the `log` file has not been opened, except of course for a short time just after job name has
>   become nonzero.
>
> **534.** The *open_log_file* routine...
>
> [...]
>   **if** *job_name* = 0 **then** *job_name* ← "`texput`";
>   [...]

Comment: ...this is a minor supplement to David's answer.

Comment: Pretty hefty supplement I'd say. I almost gave the answer to you for writing a more detailed, time-consuming explanation. Nonetheless, David's also provides useful information. I'd be interested in understanding how to use `\jobname` in `xstring`'s `\IfEq{}{}{}{}`, for example, where it needs to be expanded at a very specific time in order to be true, like why `\IfEq{\jobname}{<nameoffile>}{TRUE}{FALSE}` does not become TRUE. It seems `\jobname` can be expanded, but only sometimes (when the log is written-if I understand you correctly.)

Comment: @macmadness86: As David says, `\jobname` has to be expanded. Try with `\expandafter\IfEq\expandafter{\jobname}{<nameoffile>}{TRUE}{FALSE}`... When the `.log` is *opened*...

Comment: That code is still not expanding it at the right time, but I verified that the strings are equal with `\typeout{**** \jobname}`. Filename=test.tex and my code was therefore `\expandafter\IfEq\expandafter{\jobname}{test}{TRUE}{FALSE}` Result: FALSE, typeout shows `**** test`. This is baffling me a bit, and because  `\IfEq\expandafter{\jobname}{test}{TRUE}` results in TRUEFALSE

Comment: @macmadness86 beware that `\jobname` produces catcode 12 tokens, I don't know how `\IfEq` of `xstring` acts. To produce on your own catcode 12 "letters" (for comparison), something like `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble\expandafter\string\csname FOOBAR\endcsname` (assuming `\escapechar` is standard) is a possibility.

Comment: "supplement" translating to "I'm learning from egreg how to try to steal ticks by writing second answers ten times longer than the first posted answer":-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  It was a nice gesture by Werner to recognize you, being as you have a mere 302k points. Your answer sticks to the point and I recognize that. I do, generally speaking, like longer, more informative answers because I like to understand the relationships between things-I must admit. His answer did almost steal the gold metal-egreg style :-) Better luck next time, Werner.

Comment: @jfbu Excellent comment about the catcodes. It led me to here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/can-i-convert-a-string-to-catcode-11, which I think is relevant to mention here for future reference.